# jdbctemplate, jpatemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

in my dao, in each method, when i call jdbctemplate, i should call with new jdbctemplate().  right? or get one static instant of jdbctemplate and reuse ? how about jpatemplate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in my dao, in each method, when i call jdbctemplate, i should call with new jdbctemplate(). right?

no, you don't. the `JdbcTemplace` should be injected in your DAO by configuration. Ditto for `JpaTemplate`.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the other answers, `JdbcTemplate` is very lightweight, and its cost of construction is near-zero. So if you *were* to create a new one on every operation, there likely wouldn't be any side-effects or meaningful performance degradation. The class is merely a behavioural wrapper around the JDBC API. By the same logic, there's no reason to be careful about making sure you only have one `JdbcTemplate` object. It should fit whichever design you choose to use.

Most DAOs do dot instantiate `JdbcTemplate` directly. Instead, they subclass `JdbcDaoSupport`, which manage a `JdbcTemplate` instance for you. Your subclass then calls `getJdbcTemplate()` to fetch the instance. If you're not subclassing JdbcDaoSupport, then create an instance of `JdbcTemplate` when your DAO bean is initialized, and re-use it.

The same applies to the other DAO template classes (Hibernate, JPA, etc).

Answer (score 1):

JdbcTemplate is threadsafe so it's completely safe to share one instance of it across your entire application (*although only sharing the DataSource used to init the JdbcTemplate may make more sense*). Generally one (non-static) instance per class is enough, JdbcTemplate handles threading issues by itself and you'll never hit any concurrency issues with it beyond database locks.